# Adding an attribute to an element in a given location using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

Is it possible to add a new attribute to an xml element that already contains other attributes but not have it default to be the first attribute.

For example, I have an xml element like this:

```
<datapoint type="Footnote" subtype="" name="SecurityCusipFootnote" display="always" />
```

and I want to add an attribute called 'value'.

If I use this code in my stylesheet:

```
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:attribute name="value">
    <xsl:value-of select="42"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:copy>
```

then the transformation reads

```
<datapoint value="42" type="Footnote" subtype="" name="SecurityCusipFootnote" display="always" />
```

Is it possible to specifically place the new attribute so it appears after an existing attribute so that the transformation would read this instead

```
<datapoint type="Footnote" subtype="" name="SecurityCusipFootnote" value="42" display="always" />
```

with the new 'value' attribute appearing after the 'name' attribute.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not work, depending on how your specific processor decides to handle the task:

```
<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="datapoint/@name">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <xsl:attribute name="value">
        <xsl:value-of select="42"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Why is this a concern at all? The [XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags) states explicitly that the order of attributes is not significant.

Comment: Thanks @Michael.hor257k. It probably is nothing I should be concerned with. The only reason I asked is because my boss wanted to know if it was possible and I didn't have a clue.

Comment: @FordPrefect141 Is your question answered?